# How to group rows

Tags: group-by, sqlite

I don't understand how to retrieve the results from the following tables depending on some prerequisites.

I have 2 tables

### Table "project"

```
| id | category_id | count_view 
| -- | ------------| ---------- 
| 1  | 1           | 100      
| 2  | 2           | 50        
| 3  | 3           | 60
```

### Table "translations projects"

```
| id | project_id | name      | lang_code
| -- | -----------| ----------| ---------
| 1  | 1          | some name1| en   
| 2  | 1          | some name2| ru     
| 3  | 2          | some name3| en    
| 4  | 3          | some name4| ru
```

### Result

I want to retrieve results like in the following examples. One condition is that if a translation exists for a preset language then retrieve the name in that language, otherwise retrieve any other language.

#### For an "en" page

```
| project_id | name      | lang_code
| -----------| ----------| ---------
| 1          | some name1| en   
| 2          | some name3| en     
| 3          | some name4| ru
```

#### For an "ru" page

```
| project_id | name      | lang_code
| -----------| ----------| ---------
| 1          | some name2| en   
| 2          | some name3| en     
| 3          | some name4| ru
```

Is it possible to achieve what I want?

I tried using `case` and `group` with the following statement:

### Example for "en" page

```
SELECT p.id, t.project_name, t.lang_code ,  p.count_view
FROM Projects p 
LEFT JOIN Translation_Projects t 
ON t.project_id = p.id 
and lang_code =
(
CASE
   WHEN t.lang_code = "en" THEN "en"   
   ELSE "ru"
END
)
```

I am using SQLite.

Comment: i.e. you want to obtain the record with the specified language if exist and with another language if specified one not exists, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET @lang := 'en'; -- or 'ru', dependent by the language you need

SELECT p.id, 
       COALESCE(t1.name,t2.name) name, 
       COALESCE(t1.lang_code,t2.lang_code) lang_code
FROM Projects p
LEFT JOIN Translation_Projects t1  ON t1.project_id = p.id 
                                  AND t1.lang_code  = @lang
LEFT JOIN Translation_Projects t2  ON t2.project_id = p.id 
                                  AND t2.lang_code != @lang
```

PS. You may replace the `@lang` variable with the literal you need in a query text, of course, having 2 static queries, dynamic SQL or a query with a parameter.

PPS. Assume there will be 3rd language never...